# Retrieving an iterator's ComputedObject

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am working on a project to determine surface lake area on glaciers over a specific period of time using Google Earth Engine. So far I have used the map function on the collection to apply an atmospheric correction:  https://github.com/MarcYin/SIAC_GEE/tree/master/SIAC, and wish to use the iterator function to compute the lake area with masking and region reduction. The user supplied function will take as an initial state an empty dictionary and then return one which is filled with date/surface_area as a key/value pairs.

My issue is on the completion of the iteration, when trying to output the results, Earth engine is unable to 'convert the object to string'. I have tried using the getInfo() and evaluate() with their own method for printing server side key/value pairs, with little to no progress. I am curious if this is because I am passing in a client object and it is getting 'lost' in the server and what a solution to my issue is. Code for the method is below.

```
var Sent_2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2"),
    roi = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point([-33.00284840744821, 68.64449331362277]),
    gbl_1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-33.5420664400674, 68.76967243725574],
          [-33.411603793583026, 68.70842123723138],
          [-33.304487094364276, 68.73383850014223],
          [-33.320966586551776, 68.78905843301813]]]);

//----------------------ATCORR FUNCTION-----------------------------------------
// Use this function to correct all the images in the collection, then you will
// need to use an iteration or map function to go through each image in that
// collection to calculate the surface area.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Area of Interest (AOI) and User parameters
// Sets up the entire region to have the desired cloud coverage, location,
// dates, etc
Map.setCenter(-33.00,68.64,9);
var glacier = ee.Geometry.Point(-33.00,68.64);
var polygon = glacier.buffer(20000).bounds();//
var start_date = '2016-05-01';
var end_date   = '2016-08-14';

var criteria = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(glacier), ee.Filter.date(start_date, end_date));
var cloud_perc = 10;//Max cloud percentile per scene.

var K_glacier = ee.ImageCollection(Sent_2)
                .filter(criteria)
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud_perc));

//Function for mapping the correction across the entire image collection
function Sent2AtCorr(image) {

    // - Import the SIAC atmospheric correction module
    var siac = require('users/marcyinfeng/utils:SIAC');

    var S2_boa = siac.get_sur(image);
    return S2_boa;

}

//this is the data to be passed on to following functions
var Sent2_atCorr = K_glacier.map(Sent2AtCorr);
print(Sent2_atCorr);



//** method adapted from SIAC, <https://github.com/MarcYin/SIAC_GEE>, and
//   Yin, F., Lewis, P. E., Gomez-Dans, J., & Wu, Q. (2019, February 21).
//   A sensor-invariant atmospheric correction method: application to Sentinel-2/MSI and Landsat 8/OLI.
//   https://doi.org/10.31223/osf.io/ps957

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions and settings for use in the iteration method whcih calculates the 
// Surface area of the lakes
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//create a list of the image collection images
var imageList = K_glacier.toList(K_glacier.size());
print(imageList);


//Function to create a mask function for the NDWI to get all water pixels
function h20mask(image) {
   return image.updateMask(image.gt(0.2));
}


//Function to determine the total area of lakes from all of the boundaries in the study area
function sumArea(arr) {
  var km_const = 1000000;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var temporary = arr[i].getInfo();
    sum+= temporary['constant'];
  }
  return sum/km_const;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mapping to clip the atmospherically corrected images to the glacier boundaries
// Since the server side cannot accompany user defined geometry in the iteration fucntion
// the images must be clipped to the specified boundaries first
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function img_clip(image) {
  return image.clip(gbl_1)
  
}

var sent2_atcor_clip = Sent2_atCorr.map(img_clip);


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ITERATION STEP
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//the initial state of the object to be returned, an empty dictonary 
var SGLA_dict = ee.Dictionary({});

//function for the iterator
//the iterator takes in an argument for the current image and the result of the previous image

function calc_SGLA(current, previous) {
  
  
    var NDWI = current.expression(
      "(BLUE - RED) / (BLUE + RED)",
      {
      RED: current.select("B4"),    // RED
      NIR: current.select("B8"),    // NIR
      BLUE: current.select("B2")    // BLUE
      });

    //create a mask function for the NDWI to get all water pixels
    var h20_mask = h20mask(NDWI);

    //Using expression on the masked image to create binary 1 = water, 0 = not water
    var Sent_to2 = h20_mask.expression(
        '0 * S2', {
        'S2': h20_mask
        });

    var Sent_to3 = Sent_to2.expression(
        '1 + S2', {
        'S2': Sent_to2
        });

    //Generate the area and stats for the boundary area in the single image, add to an array of
    //boundary areas
    var S1_area = Sent_to3.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

    var stats = S1_area.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: gbl_1,
      scale: 10,
      tileScale: 16
      });
      

    // Get the timestamp and convert it to a date.
    var date = ee.Date(current.get('system:time_start'));

    //add the date/SA stats to the dictionary as a key value pair
    var last_dict = ee.Dictionary(previous);
    var updated = last_dict.set(ee.Date(date), stats);
    return ee.Dictionary(updated);
    //return stats;
}

//the final result and the call to the iterator which takes the function and the initial state as
//the arguments
var result = ee.Dictionary(Sent2_atCorr.iterate(calc_SGLA, SGLA_dict));


print('result ', ee.Dictionary(result));



print(result.evaluate(function(result) {
                            print('Client-side operations to print all key-value pairs');
                            result.keys().forEach(function(key) {
                            print('    ' + key + ': ' + result[key]);
                                });
                             }));
```

Answer (score 1):

They way you construct your dictionary inside the iterate function is not allowed for server side processing, also the input arguments for your dictionary constructor are not allowed, which is why it throws your error.
This might work technically, not sure if the outputs are what you expect:

```
function calc_SGLA(current, previous) {
  // var current = sent2_atcor_clip.first()
  // print(current, 'current')
    var NDWI = current.expression(
      "(BLUE - RED) / (BLUE + RED)",
      {
      RED: current.select("B4"),    // RED
      NIR: current.select("B8"),    // NIR
      BLUE: current.select("B2")    // BLUE
      });

    //create a mask function for the NDWI to get all water pixels
    var h20_mask = h20mask(NDWI);

    //Using expression on the masked image to create binary 1 = water, 0 = not water
    var Sent_to2 = h20_mask.expression(
        '0 * S2', {
        'S2': h20_mask
        });

    var Sent_to3 = Sent_to2.expression(
        '1 + S2', {
        'S2': Sent_to2
        });

    //Generate the area and stats for the boundary area in the single image, add to an array of
    //boundary areas
    var S1_area = Sent_to3.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

    var stats = S1_area.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: gbl_1,
      scale: 10,
      tileScale: 16
      }).get('constant');

    // Get the timestamp and convert it to a date.
    var date = ee.Date(current.get('system:time_start'));
    
    //add the date/SA stats to the dictionary as a key value pair
    var last_dict = ee.Dictionary(previous);
    var updated = last_dict.set(date.millis(), stats);
   
    return updated;
    //return stats;
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9369fe8a0bbe13d678ddca851a1cd346

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `iterate()`, since you don't use the previous state for anything during the calculations.  Iterate doesn't scale well and breaks all parallelism.  You should use `map()` and convert the results to a dictionary at the end.

Comment: But doesn't map() only return an image? Then I would just have a collection of images which I would need to go through again to gain the statistics I need.

Comment: No, you can return a feature too (just wrap the dictionary in a Feature: `return ee.Feature(null, updated)`